# Initializing values at the end of a pointer to pointer to pointer chain

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Alright I've been cranking away at this all day (not hw), and though it may not be a particularly useful bit of code, it is a neat conceptual thing. I am trying to figure out the best way to set a value at the end of, for lack of a better name, a pointer to pointer to pointer chain. For example, I declare:

```
int *****ptr;
```

What is the best way to set each pointer to pointer segment, all the way down to the actual int value?

This code doesn't compile because it doesn't like the way I use and dereference void pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMPOINTERS 5

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *****number;
    *****number = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    void *ptr = *number;

    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < NUMPOINTERS; i++)
    {
        if(i == NUMPOINTERS - 1)
        {
            ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
            int *iPtr = (int*)ptr;
            *iPtr = 900;
            break;
        }

        *ptr = malloc(sizeof(void*));
        ptr = **ptr;
    }

    printf("%d", *****number);

    return 0;

}
```

Is there some article out there that talks about ridiculous numbers of pointers to pointers and how to work with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is pretty close.  You probably want to work from the inside out, though.  Here's a complete example based on your program (comments inline):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMPOINTERS 5

int main(void)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocate space for the integer value
    *(int *)ptr = 900;               // initialize it 

    // iterate to create the nested pointers
    for (int i = 1; i < NUMPOINTERS; i++)
    {
        void **newptr = malloc(sizeof(void *)); // create a new pointer
        *newptr = ptr;                          // point it at what we have so far
        ptr = newptr;                           // "step out" one level
    }

    int *****number = ptr;        // make our 'int *****' pointer
    printf("%d\n", *****number);  // dereference and print the pointed-to value

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are a hero, thanks! It's been one of those things where I won't do anything else but just stare at the screen. I didn't know you could do assignments like the 9th line of your program.

Comment: A quick question. When you put a line like this:

int *pointer = someOtherPtr;

pointer will take on the address that someOtherPtr was pointing to and not just point to that pointer because it isn't a pointer to a pointer.

However, a void pointer can point to whatever it wants. It has no type. So when you assign a pointer to a void pointer with the '=' operator, how does the compiler decide whether to point at the pointer or point to what it was pointing at, because a void pointer can point at a pointer or just a value?

ie: ptr = newptr;

Comment: If there are no `&` or `*` operators, both `pointer` and `someOtherPtr` point to the same memory location. The same happens with `void *` pointers.  So with `void *p = q;`, both `p` and `q` point to the same memory location.  With `void *p = &q`, `p` points to `q` itself.

Comment: So in that case, the program in your answer doesn't really have pointers pointing to other pointers. They are just pointing to the same memory location as the first one? It seems like number is just pointing to an int in that case.

Comment: No, `****number` points to an `int`.  `number` points to `*number`, `*number` points to `**number`, `**number` points to `***number`, and `***number` points to `****number`.  How would the `*****number` dereferencing in the `printf` call work otherwise?

Comment: So in this:
`code`
    int *woo = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *woo = 8;
    int ***************hoo = woo;
`code`
*hoo is actually 8 and not a ptr to a ptr to a ptr etc... even though I declared it to be.

Comment: @Matt, yes, that's right.  That code wont compile without warnings, though.  What you declare the variable as has nothing to do with it.  If you don't indirect enough times, you're not going to end up with a matching data structure.  Maybe you should look at some of these constructs in a debugger?