# Why does gcc allow dereferencing to occur when the pointer isn't pointing at the correct type. Why even have types?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, types, dereference

I posted yesterday about pointers to pointers to pointers etc. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915046/initializing-values-at-the-end-of-a-pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-chain/15915188?noredirect=1#comment22673098_15915188) and decided to move the discussion in the comments of the answer to a new question.

My question is why does the compiler allow for this to happen:

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));
*foo = 8;
int **********blarg = foo;
```

I get some warnings, but when I do a dereference on blarg like this:

```
*blarg;
```

It's value is 8. Shouldn't the dereference return some type of null value? Shouldn't the compiler know that only after a dereference such as:

```
**********blarg;
```

is there an actual integer value and any lower level of dereferences will only return more pointers to pointers?

Void pointers are a whole new level of confusion for me, because a variable like this:

```
void *asdf;
```

could point to any of these types:

```
int
char
float
*void
**********void
*******int
```

You get the point.

So my main questions:

1. What is really going on in the first snippet of code? Are those pointers to pointers even being created?
2. Why does the dereference work in the second snippet of code?
3. (And as stupid as it sounds) Why even have types if I can assign any value to anything and have
   it work as long as I read it correctly?

Comment: People who are careful shouldn't have to take a performance hit because it checks every dereference.

Comment: The compiler gave you a warning. If your question is, why did the compiler allow the code to compile - use `-Werror` (gcc), it won't compile anymore and you will no longer need to worry if your code has the above mentioned illegal behavior.

Comment: I guess a better question would be what does it even compile to so that it even runs? Wish I new assembly.

Comment: @chris: Isn't this a compile-time concern?

Comment: @recursive, I sensed some of the compile-time concerns. I thought the question encompassed runtime matters as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's a great point. I suppose what I am trying to figure out is what the default behavior is when it isn't really defined.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a simpler example:

```
int n;
int *p = &n;
int **p2 = p;
```

Using gcc 4.7, with default options, I get:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

The C Standard says that the attempted initialization of `p2` is a *constraint violation*, which means that a conforming implementation is required to issue a diagnostic. It *doesn't* mean that a conforming implementation is required to reject the translation unit. The only case where a translation unit (source file) must be rejected is when it contains a `#error` directive.

So by printing a warning for the invalid initializer, gcc has done its job as far as the ISO C standard is concerned.

If you want it to reject it outright, you can use the `-pedantic-errors` option, preferably along with one of the `-std=...` options.

That's the language issue. gcc *could* reject such programs by default -- so why doesn't it? That's a question about gcc, not about the C language.

gcc has been around for a long time, since before the official C standard was published by ANSI in 1989. In the pre-ANSI days, it wasn't as clear that an initializer like this was illegal. There was (and likely still is) a fair amount of old code that depends on constructs like this, and happens to work. I speculate that the gcc developers just haven't felt that there was a good time to make such a change and risk breaking existing code.

Personally, I *wish* gcc would reject things like this by default, but you can always (a) enable stricter diagnostics, and (b) pay close attention to warnings.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question.

It boils down to realizing, the value of the C language boasting a type system is the the following promise: "if your code does not trigger warnings, then it is typesafe in the frames of the C type system". A lot of errors that the programmer could make are being brought to his attention. And vice versa, if the compilers emits no warnings, the programmer can have a certain level of trust that his code does not contain any of a vast class of issues. An assembly programmer cannot be this certain and may have to double check everything. But a C programmer only has to double check the higher level aspects of the code, than errors such as forgeting to dereference a pointer.

`(void*)` is often used there, where it is impossible or inconvenient to tie the functions, structures, ... with a specific type. Examples include collections, message passing primitives.

Your code triggers warnings, so of course the compiler does not state that your code is typesafe, and indeed, accessing `**blarg` while `(int)*blarg == 8` would cause a memory access error on many an architecture. (Even as `**` is not the final level of derefence.)

You're asking if the pointers to pointers are being created: when you say

```
int **********blarg [...] ; //10-pointer to int
```

You're only creating one variable, which is a pointer to a 9-pointer to int. This line is not creating and not supposed to create the 9-pointer to int, which `blarg` will point at.

Comment: So a printf("%d", *blarg); works because of the context the variable is being used in? It expects whatever it is passed to be an int. However, if something expected *blarg to be a pointer to an "8-pointer" and tried to dereference it like **blarg, you would get problems? Or would it just be pointing to memory address 8?

Comment: `printf("%d", *blarg)` works, because `blarg` is initialized with an address in memory, but this code emits a warning with gcc. Also, `int *ptr; printf("%f, %d", ptr, 1234);` will fail to print the number 1234 on amd64, as printf would expect a 4byte float unpadded on the stack, while the pointer is 8 bytes.

Comment: @Adrain Panasiuk So why wouldn't printf just read the first 4 bytes of ptr like it does when I pass a long to a `printf("%d", longVar)`

Comment: It does, interprets it as a float, then interprets the rest as an int; and does not have any flags left that tell it to interpret the 1234.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your code carefully.  I note that you are almost certainly compiling in a 32-bit mode (either on a 32-bit machine or on a 64-bit machine in 32-bit mode).

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));
*foo = 8;
int **********blarg = foo;
*blarg;
```

The first line assigns a pointer to `foo`, and the pointer points to a space big enough to hold an `int`.  The second line assigns the value `8` to the integer that `foo` points at.

The third line with the 10 levels of pointer (10 `*`'s) generates a warning because the type of `foo` does not match the type of `blarg`.  However, the compiler tries to make head or tail of what you do, and copies the pointer from `foo` into `blarg`.

The fourth line accesses the value that `blarg` points at.  The result is an `int *** *** ***` (9-levels of pointer to int), but its value is what `blarg` points at.  Since you see `8` as the value of `*blarg`, we can reasonably infer that `sizeof(int *) == sizeof(int)` — hence my observation about 32-bit compilation.  If you were on a 64-bit machine (even Windows 64), `*blarg` would access 8 bytes instead of 4, and the chances are that the extra 4 bytes would not all be zero.

So, the behaviour is predictable, even if you didn't expect it.  But it is not strictly defined because of the type mismatch in the assignment to `blarg`.  You also could not safely use `**blarg` or any other larger number of dereferencing `*`'s; you'd be accessing invalid memory.

Comment: I see. So if foo were a pointer to a long. This wouldn't even complile? Actually let me check... OK it compiles, but when I print *blarg as an int, it reads the value as if it were an int, and disregards the remaining bits.

Comment: If you're on a 32-bit system, then `*blarg` prints a 32-bit pointer value.  You'd have to be on a 64-bit system to see problems, and even that is not guaranteed with the code as written.  If you allocated `int *foo = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` and then assigned `foo[0] = 8; foo[1] = 0xA0B1C2D3;` and then tried printing `*blarg` using: `printf("*blarg = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(*blarg));`, then you'd see a combination of 0x00000008 and 0xA0B1C2D3 in the output, but the order depends on whether you're using a big-endian or little-endian machine, in part.